# How To Pass a Dictionary To a Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, methods, return-value

Alright, so I think I'm doing this the right way.  I'm new to objective-C, so I'm not sure about the syntax...  I have a set of code that I need to call multiple times, from different files.  So I made a new class that has a method in it that I'll call and pass it the values that it needs.

Because I am passing different values I've put them in a dictionary and decided to just pass the dictionary.  Here is that code:

```
NSNumber *testNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:varMoney];


    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setObject:@"OMG, Object 1!!!!" forKey:@"1"];
    [dictionary setObject:@"Number two!" forKey:@"2"];
    [dictionary setObject:testNum forKey:@"3"];
```

This code creates a test variable, and then puts it into the dictionary "dictionary."  That all works, I have my nice little dictionary.  However, now I need to create the class and it's method that will recieve the dictionary, and do something with it.

This is my class header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface EndOfTurnObjC : UIView {

}

@end
```

And this is the implementation file:

```
#import "EndOfTurnObjC.h"


@implementation EndOfTurnObjC


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I haven't created any of the real code, because I'm not sure how to do the passing.  I need to create a function (Method?) in the class that will take a Dictionary has a parameter, and then return the dictionary.

I also have no idea how to call such a function because it's in the class.  So, the questions are:
1:  How do I define the method in the class to accept the dictionary as a parameter (and then perhaps some example code to pull out one of the objects in a dictionary, so I can be sure it works)

2:  How do I return the dictionary at the end of the method?

3:  How do I call this method, in the class, from another class?  (I know it involves making an object of thing class and calling the method of the object... I think, but I'm not sure about the syntax.)

Please include relavent code for the 3 files (header, implementation, and the other class that I call from).  Thank you so much, I've been working on this particular problem for a while now.

Comment: "Please include relavent code for the 3 files " - I'm not a typical "google it" or "no homework" or "rtfm" person, but you're kind of asking a lot from us without really providing any proof of effort. These things aren't that complicated, and we'd be glad to help you, but I'm pretty sure many of us would like to at least see your attempts first.

Comment: I could give you the source code for my app, but that isn't quite the idea.  I've done a lot of work on my program, but I can't find any documentation on this.  I don't want people to do any work for me either, but after working on this problem for 2 weeks, I've reached the end of my ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) doSomethingWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *) aDict;
```

in the implementation:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) doSomethingWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *) aDict{
    //do something with the dictionary 
    return aDict;
}
```

To call the method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *returnDict=[EndOfTurnObjC doSomethingWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

Note that as a matter of good design you wouldn't want to pass a mutable dictionary around like a token. That is asking for trouble. Instead pass static dictionaries and get another dictionary back.

You also shouldn't be passing data to a UIView. Instead, your UIViewController should process the data and then populate the view's UI elements as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/index.html) is a good and pretty concise reference for Objective-C syntax. What you want is just a normal method that takes an NSDictionary as a parameter. So as given in that document:

> A message with a single argument affixes a colon (:) to the selector name and puts the argument right after the colon. This construct is called a keyword; a keyword ends with a colon, and an argument follows the colon, as shown in this example:

```
[myRectangle setWidth:20.0];
```

So a method call to pass `dictionary` would look like:

```
[someObject setAttributes:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to do stuff to your dictionary u just

-(void) changeMyDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary * ) dictionary_

{

```
[dictionary_ doStuff];
    ....
    ...
```

}

no need to return the dictionary.